# Is it possible to bind data without refresh page using knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-ajax

I am using knockout data binding. When I drag and drop div in another div at that time I am calling one validation in popup. When I close popup I need to rebind data without page refresh.

Ex. I am using below code for the bind data.

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(),
$("#bindappointment")[0]);

Comment: welcome to stack refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for somethign like this. You need to clean the node then you will be able to rebind without reloading the page.

```
var element = $('#elementId')[0]; 
ko.cleanNode(element);
```

and then

```
ko.applyBindings(myVieModel, parentDiv)
```